# Can we mock a web container in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, webserver, websphere-8

I want to run my JSP as a stand alone component. I want to mock a web container and run my jsp in it. I am curious if there is a way to mock a server's web container (Web Server)?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am working to develope a standalone JSP testing unit. Need to mock a container to run a servlet compiled from JSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you might be interested in [Arquillian and Shrinkwrap](http://arquillian.org/guides/shrinkwrap_introduction/). It allows you to perform in-container testing easily.